# MySQL: Can I stop an UPDATE query in the BEFORE UPDATE trigger?

Tags: mysql, triggers, kill

Title pretty much says it.

```
IF NEW.variance <> 0 
THEN (kill update)
END IF
```

Is this possible?

Comment: What version of MySql are you on?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the manual (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/signal.html) the `SIGNAL` statement is what you are looking for.

```
IF NEW.variance <> 0 
THEN
    SIGNAL error 
    SET MESSAGE_TEXT='Variance is not 0.';
END IF
```